# Angle between tangential line and centerline of eccentrically spinning circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Pictured in Figure 1, there are two equally sized, eccentrically mounted circles with radius ***r=25***, turning around centerpoints with distance ***a=100*** with eccentricity ***e=10***. The numerical values are given for clarity only. The line at the top connects both circles tangentially. The circles spin around their centers with a phase difference of 180°, meaning the lines connecting the circles' centers to the centers of rotation are always parallel, but point in opposite directions. There are (objectively poorly drawn) angles ***α*** and ***β***, with ***α*** being the angle between the horizontal and tangential line. I'm now trying to find an equation for ***α*** as a function of ***β***.

[image: Figure 1, sketch]

While I expected this to be sinusoidal, I let a CAD program do some computations and according to Figure 2, it seems just about not to be.

[image: Figure 2, CAD results]

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Is angle α between fixed points on the circles, or the tangent line wherever that is? This is awfully close to a swinging-arm cam follower, or a four-bar linkage. I can't decide.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Angle α is supposed to be between the horizontal line and the tangential line up top. Increasing β of course shifts/tilts the tangential line, and as such changes α (α is supposed to be 0° for β=0° and β=180°). I have updated my question to include this clarification. Thank you for providing some keywords, although neither brings up any information that covers my problem (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a rotated diagram that keeps the tangent line horizontal. Also the angle $\alpha$ can describe the following triangle

[image: fig1]

In the picture above the known distances $a$ and $e$ are fixed, as well as the angle $\beta$ at any instant. The result of the kinematics is the distance $b$ between the centers and the angle $\alpha$.

Describe the (x,y) coordinates of the pivot points relative to the center (between the two circles) as

$$\begin{aligned}b/2+e\cos\beta & =a/2\cos\alpha &  & \text{x-axis}\\
e\sin\beta & =a/2\sin\alpha &  & \text{y-axis}
\end{aligned}
$$

and solve for

$$\begin{aligned}b= & \sqrt{a^{2}-4e^{2}\sin^{2}\beta}-2e\cos\beta\\
\tan\alpha & =\frac{2e\sin\beta}{b+2e\cos\beta}
\end{aligned}$$

Note that for $e \ll a$ you have approximately

$$ \tan( \alpha)  \approx \frac{2 e}{a} \sin \beta$$
or

$$ \tan( \alpha)  \approx \frac{2 e}{a} \sin \beta + \frac{4 e^3}{a^3} \sin^3 \beta$$

Based on the above if you plotted the angle $\beta$ versus $\tan \alpha$ you would see a much better match for the sine curve based on the first approximation above.

Comment: John, thank you so much for your detailed answer. After careful consideration, I'm unsure if I may have miscommunicated my fixed dimensions and relations, as I'm currently unable to directly relate your (much nicer ;) ) diagram to mine. One of the main things that surprised me and which (to me) seems like a major difference is that the distance between the horizontal and a point on the tangential which lies vertical to the midpoint of the horizontal is not fixed, but changes when changing β.

Comment: Scratch that, while recreating your setup in CAD, it clicked for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Take your diagram and make the line connecting the center points of the circles horizontal _at each time frame_ and then you have my diagram. The distance $a$ is fixed, and $b$ varies by angle of rotation.

Comment: This now makes a lot more sense. Off topic, but may I ask which software you used to generate your diagram?

Comment: @Luap - I used PowerPoint for the diagram, with [IguanaTex](https://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) addin to add LaTeX math on it. It is just lines, with shapes added to the end of them to look like points.